# Merging a dataframe containing a geometry list

Tags: r, r-sf

I want to merge two dataframes on their zipcode variable, where one of my dataframes contains a 'geometry' list with Multipolygons.

```
merged <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = "key_in_1", by.y = "key_in_2", all.x = TRUE) #
```

this gives the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_bbox") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_

bbox' applied to an object of class "list"
```

The geometry column in `df2` has the following shape:

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shape[[37]][[1]] | list [1] (S3:XY, MULTIPOLYGON, sfg) | List of length 1 |
| [[1]] | list[1] | List of length 1 |

Edit:

```
class(df1) #gives "SF" "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"
class(df2) #gives "data.frame"

dput(head(df2))
structure(list(Category = c(3818L, 4721L, 4722L, 4731L, 4827L, 
4841L), x = c(8, 39, 2, 58, 43, 74)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Unfortunately I cannot copy the output of `dput(head(df1))` since it is too long, it contains a column with zipcodes and a column with the multipolyon data.

Comment: Looks like these are not data frames. There is a method to [`merge`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/merge.sf.html) `sf` objects with data frames - although what you end up with can depend on which one is `x` and which one is `y`. But it looks like you're trying to a merge a bounding box? I'm not sure how that makes sense... What does `class(df1)` and `class(df2)` give you? Can you edit the question to add the output of `dput(head(df1))` and `dput(head(df2))`?

Comment: Df2 is a simple data.frame, Df1 contains the multipolygon table. I edited the question but could not include the output of dput(head((df1)) because it is too extensive.

The goal is to merge them on zipcode.